# How to extend url_for to provide dynamic default parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out a clean and dry way to extend the url_for such that it provides a dynamically based default parameter.  I know that sounds weird, let me explain:

I have a set of nested resource routes that sit beneath a dynamic scope:

```
scope "/:network", constraints: {:network => /[^\/]+/} do
  constraints DomainConstraint.new do
     resources :users do
       resources :posts
     end
  end
end
```

This gives routes like:

```
/mysite.com/users/mike
/someothersite.com/users/sally
```

In order to generate these routes in a view, I can easily do:

```
mike = User.find_by_name("mike")
sally = User.find_by_name("sally")
user_path(mike.network, mike)
user_path(sally.network, sally)
```

However, this does not seem very DRY to me as the network is fixed for each user.  I'd rather be able to concisely say:

```
user_path(mike)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I've come up with a solution that works, but it seems very hacky and I'm wondering if there is a more "proper" way to do it:

```
module UrlForWithDefault
  def self.included(base)
    base.module_eval do
      alias_method_chain :url_for, :default
    end
  end
  def url_for_with_default(*args)
    if args[0].kind_of?(Hash)
      opts = args[0]
      if opts.has_key?(:_positional_keys) and opts[:_positional_keys].include?(:network)
        opts[:_positional_args].unshift(opts[:_positional_args][0].network)
        url_for_without_default(opts)
      end
    end
    url_for_without_default(*args)
  end
end
ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor.send(:include, UrlForWithDefault)
```

I don't like this approach because it hacks the ":_positional_keys" and ":_positional_args" attributes, which could potentially change.

Comment: looks good, but you should use Module#prepend instead of alias_method_chain

Answer (score 0):

could not url_options or Rails.application.routes.default_url_options do what you want?

Comment: no because then it would not be both "dynamic" and "default", eg "dynamically default"...sounds contradictory...but its not :)